# Ionic 3 - Watch requests in InAppBrowser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, inappbrowser

I am using InAppBrowser plugin to redirect user to payment website. The problem is that, when payment is done , I need to close that window automatically.
Is there any way to watch requests in InAppBrowser and check them, so that I can catch the successful response and close browser?

Comment: Is that website yours? If not, how do you figure out whether event is triggered or not?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you listen to page load events or other events happening in the InAppBrowser. Here is an example of using the Cordova plugin directly (without Ionic Native):

```
  browser.addEventListener("loadstart", (event) => {
    if ((event.url).indexOf("http://localhost/callback") === 0) {

      browser.removeEventListener("exit", (event) => {});
      browser.close();

      // do things with `event.url` here
    }
  });
```

Comment: I tried that thing, but it shows only first load (when I do ExecuteScript action). Then when some actions in payment form are done, nothing is shown.